# Telegram bot Copyrights symbol is grey

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I have an InlineKeyboardMarkup like:

```
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
   InlineKeyboardButton('©', callback_data='©'),
   InlineKeyboardButton('a', callback_data='a'),
   InlineKeyboardButton('b', callback_data='b')
])
```

And whenever I show it the copyrights symbol is colored grey but all other buttons are white as they should

I was wondering why only the copyrights symbol is in grey and how to fix this

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How exactly the buttons are displayed is up to the client (which Telegram App/Web app/desktop opp you're using). You can't influence that via the Bot API.